# Rails Frontend, Backend, and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-api

Does your Rails app have to be API-Only to be able to use the API generator? I want to create my fronted and backend using Ruby on Rails. Then build a mobile using the API.

Answer (score 2):

> Does your Rails app have to be API-Only to be able to use the API
>   generator?

No, it can be a normal web application and you can build an API alongside it. The term *API-only* came from Rails 5 where it introduced a way to generate a Rails API-only applications that are different from normal web applications. For more information, have a look into these [*guides*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can access your API throught a different route, as in www.myapp.com/api/request, and access your Rails application throught www.myapp.com/request, for example